# Isomorphism between vector space and dual space

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

My teacher told me if two finite dimensional vector space have same dimension, then they're isomorphic.

According to this, shouldn't every FDVS be isomorphic to its dual?

Comment: But it *is* isomorphic! (through dual bases).

Comment: And thus naturally, double dual is also isomorphic to the vector space. So why do we explicitly prove it?

Comment: The double-dual is *canonically* isomorphic to the vector space, not the dual.

Comment: Yes, a finite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to its dual. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: I actually got confused because we speak about a vector space isomorphic to double dual but never to its dual.

Comment: The difference is that there is an isomorphism $V \cong V^{**}$ that does not depend on choosing a basis for $V$ while no such constructions exists for an isomorphism $V \cong V^{*}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A finite dimensional vector space $V$ is always isomorphic to its dual space $V^*$. 
This is a consequence of the fact that $V$ and $V^*$ have the same dimension.

We can easily see this finding a bases for $V^*$. If $(\vec e_i)$ is the canonical basis of $V$ such that any vector can be expressed as $\vec v=v_1 \vec e_1+v_2 \vec e_2 +\cdots +v_n\vec e_n$.

Consider the linear functionals $f_i$ defined by $ f_i (\vec v)= v_i$.

So, for the vectors of the basis we have $f_i(\vec e_j)=\delta_{i,j}$
and any linear functional can be expressed as a linear combination of $(f_i)$, so $(f_i)$ is a basis of $V^*$.